# Rails 4. Moving form information from one controller (with no model), to another (no model) in order to pass arguments to a method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

I have a simple app where users will be able to purchase items.  On item pages there will be an add to cart button.  The carts-controller displays the items using REDIS relationship, it has no model.  Once the user has reviewed the items and wishes to buy, they will be directed to purchases view where once they pay with stripe, an order will be created in purchases-controller.  The purchases controller also has no model.

The user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders

    def get_cart_items
        cart_ids = REDIS.smembers "cart#{id}"
        Item.find(cart_ids)
    end

    def purchase_cart_items!(recipient_name:, recipient_address:)
        get_cart_items.each { |item| purchase!(item, recipient_name, recipient_address) }
        REDIS.del "cart#{id}"
    end

    def purchase!(item, recipient_name, recipient_address)
        self.orders.create!(user_email: self.email,
                            item_id: item.id,
                            recipient_name: recipient_name)
                            recipient_address: recipient_address)                     
   end
end
```

The purchases-controller:

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        Stripe::Charge.create(
        ...
        )
        ##########
        current_user.purchase_cart_items!(recipient_name:, recipient_address:)
        ##########
    end
end
```

The carts-controller:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        REDIS.sadd current_user_cart, params[:item_id]
    end
    def destroy
        REDIS.srem current_user_cart, params[:item_id]
    end
 end
```

Creating the Order attributes of `user_email:` and `item_id:` is easy by calling `self.email` and `item.id` since they are attached to a model, but I am unsure of how to use a form in the ***carts view*** to have the user input the `recipient_name:` and `recipient_address:` arguments for `purchase_cart_items!(recipient_name:, recipient_address:)` method in the *purchases-controller*.

I need to:

1. Create a form in the carts view where the user can input arguments for a method in another controller
2. Upon submission of the form details, I need the user to be redirected to purchases view
3. The form information has to be then passed as an argument to a method in the purchases-controller

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `form_tag` with a GET method needs to be used in order to submit the form info to the right controller.
In the carts view:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "purchases", action: "new"}, method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag 'recipient name: ' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'recipient_name' %>
  <%= label_tag 'recipient address: ' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'recipient_address' %>
  <%= submit_tag "PAY" %>
<% end %>
```

Once in the `new` action of the purchases-controller I used `params` to get the form info and `session` to make the form information available to the create action in the same controller:

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @name = params[:name]
        @address = params[:address]
        session[:name] = @name
        session[:address] = @address
    end
    def create
        Stripe::Charge.create(
        ...
        )
    ##########
        @name = session[:name]
        @address = session[:address]
        current_user.purchase_cart_destinations!(name: @name, address: @address)
    ##########
    end
end
```

Once the form information was accessible in the `create` action of purchases-controller, the keyword arguments for `current_user.purchase_cart_items!` were easy to set with instance variables of `@name` and `@address`.